# Oracle: show records that don't meet a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I want to get a list of all cars that have not failed an inspection ever, but I have no idea how. The best I have at the moment is a list of cars that have passed.

```
SELECT c.CAR_MAKE, c.CAR_MODEL, c.CAR_REGISTRATION, COUNT(*) as "Inspections Passed" 
from inspection i
INNER JOIN car c
on i.CAR_ID = c.CAR_ID
WHERE i.INSPECTION_PASSED = '1'
GROUP BY c.CAR_MAKE,c.CAR_MODEL,c.CAR_REGISTRATION
HAVING count(*) >=1;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does a 0 mean failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is for *all* the rows in the group to have `inspection_passed = '1'`.  So, let's count them:

```
SELECT c.CAR_MAKE, c.CAR_MODEL, c.CAR_REGISTRATION,
       COUNT(*) as "Inspections Passed" 
FROM inspection i INNER JOIN
     car c
     on i.CAR_ID = c.CAR_ID
GROUP BY c.CAR_MAKE, c.CAR_MODEL, c.CAR_REGISTRATION
HAVING count(*) = SUM(case when i.INSPECTION_PASSED = '1' then 1 else 0 end);
```

If `INSPECTION_PASSED` only takes on the values `0`, `1` and `NULL` you can do:

```
HAVING count(*) = SUM(INSPECTION_PASSED);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much and thanks for a quick answer (sadly i can mark as the right answer because of silly stackoverflow rules)

Comment: The not exists solution is a bit more optimized.

Comment: `having count(case when i.inspection_passed != 1 or i.inspection_passed is null) = 0` seems quite a bit simpler. And, I agree with @TGray re: the more efficient solution.

Comment: @mathguy . . . Your code is not syntactically correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Right - because I didn't have data to test it on. But you know, of course, how to fix it. `case ... is null then 'x' end) = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get generate a set of data with all cars which have a failed inspection  and use an not exists... coorlating the subquery.   Not sure why you need a count or having.

```
SELECT c.CAR_MAKE, c.CAR_MODEL, c.CAR_REGISTRATION
FROM car c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM inspection I
                  WHERE I.Car_ID = C.car_ID  
                    and inspection_passed <> '1')
```

This assumes <> '1' means failed.

or change and `inspection_passed <> '1'` to `inspection_passed = '0'`)